# C# Reusable Mysql Class

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am having some issues with a class that I have created to perform different database commands.

1st) The program is local ran, and will only run locally. It will only ever connect to the database on the localhost.

Therefore I have a simple class setup, called databaseConnector that allows me to pass a string to it with the required Mysql query to perform the different functions.

For instance.

I use:

```
var db = new databaseConnector();
db.Update("UPDATE * WHERE.....");
```

However, it seems if I ever want to use a different query, or another query, it's not working and throwing errors.

For instance.

```
var db = new databaseConnector();
db.Update("UPDATE * WHERE...");
db.INSERT("INSERT INTO * WHERE.....");
```

Will give me an error on the insert execution. Any ideas why? I have resorted to creating it again. So I have to redo:

```
db = new databaseConnector();
```

to then use the Insert command.

Here is an example of my insert function.

```
public void Insert(string query)
{

//open connection
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
    //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

    //Execute command
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //close connection
    this.CloseConnection();
}
}
```

Now that I think about it. Should I call my db.openConnection() before doing it. Since when I initialize it in the first var db = new databaseConnection(), it's opening? And then in each function it's closing it, but only checking if it's open, instead of attempting to open, doing query, then closing.

Comment: What errors is it throwing?

Comment: I am work, so I can't actually run it. Plus, I found a way to get around it by reinitializing it. See my edits above. I think it's because I don't open the connection on each query, instead they just check if it's already open, then close it at the end.

Comment: It's not throwing any errors during runtime. It's a bot for Steam Trading, and it simply just crashes the bot.

Comment: I have found the issue. In my SELECT function I was returning before closing the connection. Therefore, it was attempting to open the connection again on the 2nd use of the SELECT function, and throwing the error.